# dimension of the space of all symmetric matrices with trace $0$ and $a_{11}=0$,

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to know the dimension of the space of all symmetric matrices with trace $0$ and $a_{11}=0$,

I can show that the dimension of space of all symmetric matrices $S$ is $n(n+1)/2$, now I give a linear map $T\colon S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ by $T(A)=(a_{11},\operatorname{trace}(A))$ so the kernel is exactly the space I want,
so now it is enough to show the map is surjective so that I can apply rank nullity theorem. am I in right path?
in that case $\dim\ker(T)=n(n+1)/2 -2$.

Comment: Yes, I think you are in the right path. Except you may need to consider the trivial case when $A$ is $1\times 1$ matrix. In that case, your $T$ is given by $T(A)=(a_{11},a_{11})$, which is not surjective.

Comment: :-o :-o :-o :-o :(, I was given $n\ge 2$

Comment: There is always the tried and tested method of counting choices. You have a choice of every element above the diagonal, which is $\frac{1}{2}(n-1)n$ choices, and a choice for every element except two on the diagonal, which is $n-2$ more choices. Giving a total of $\frac{1}{2}(n^2+n-4)=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-2$ choices.

Comment: @DanielRust Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul already noted, you are on the right path (although you have to assume that $n\geq 2$ as of course the zero matrix is the only matrix with $a_{11}=0$).

Now, how to show that this map is surjective if $n\geq 2$: Let $(r,s)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then define the symmetric matrix $A$ by $a_{11}=r$ and $a_{nn}=s-r$ and all other entries equal to zero. Then $T(A)=(r,s)$, so $T$ is surjective. Now you can apply rank-nullity and get the result you stated.

To comment on the solution that Daniel Rust gave in the comments: To define a symmetric matrix you have to give a value to each diagonal entry and to each entry above the diagonal (the values below the diagonal are then determined by $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$. There are $n$ entries on the diagonal. But $a_{11}=0$ by assumption, so there is no choice and also say, for $a_{nn}$ there is no choice as $0=\operatorname{trace}(A)=\sum a_{ii}$. Thus $a_{nn}=-\sum_{i\neq n}a_{ii}$. So you are left with $n-2$ choices. 
For the part above the diagonal note that there are $n^2$ entries of a matrix in total. Of these all but $n$ don't lie on the diagonal, that's $n^2-n$. Exactly half of them lie above the diagonal, so that's $\frac{1}{2}(n^2-n)$. For all of them you have no constraints from your conditions.
Adding all choices up, you have $(n-2)+\frac{1}{2}(n^2-n)=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-2$.